# Smoothing discrete data

Tags: c++, embedded, arm, interpolation, curve-fitting

I'm trying to write a program to smooth discrete digitized data for use in a motion simulator. The data will be provided as a set of t, x(t) points and is intended to be used to create cyclic motion; thus the smoothed data must be not only continuous over the range of t values but also between the two endpoints. In addition, data provided will most likely be of significantly lower resolution than required and thus significant interpolation will take place.

I've looked at various techniques such as Gauss-Newton and Levenberg–Marquardt curve fits, but these assume that an objective function is known beforehand (and it will not be). Unfortunately the users of said motion simulator may not be able to choose an appropriate function (due to their differing backgrounds). Finally, the code must be usable on a non-proprietary, cross-platform (and preferably compiled) language which can run on embedded platforms (most likely Linux on ARM) - this precludes the use of Maple (which provides a generic 'fit' routine that selects an appropriate objective function), Matlab (similar IIRC) or other math-related languages. I should say that I'm predisposed to C++ due to experience.

Some typical data can be found on pages [here](http://mechanical.mines.edu/courses/eggn536/Project/Literature/1992_LaFortune_knne_motion.pdf).

What technique would be useful for this?

Comment: I don't know what exactly your data looks like but polynomial fitting with an appropiate degree might be generic enough

Comment: I recall something superficially similar - fitting a continuous cyclic function to a set of points (coverted to polar coordinates) defining a vaguely circular region in an image - in which I hacked up Matlab's `polyfit` and `polyval` functions to use combinations of sin+cos instead of polynomials for the basis functions, which worked pretty well in that case. Not sure how appropriate that would be for your data, but it might be worth a thought - I'm sure there's least-squares fitting code out there for just about any language.

Answer (score 1):

It would likely be simpler and more adaptive to different data sets to apply Digital Signal Processing (DSP) techniques for rate conversion by [upsampling and interpolation](http://www.dspguru.com/dsp/faqs/multirate/interpolation). The C++ [SPUC](http://spuc.sourceforge.net/) library may help you here - it supports several [interpolation filters](http://audiofilter.github.io/spuc/group__interpolation.html).

Comment: How would this work if the data was "jagged" and imprecise? I'm not looking for something which fits all data points (as in standard interpolation) but rather smooths over the jaggedness of data with a low sample rate.

Comment: @gjsmo : That's exactly why DSP techniques are appropriate.  The "noise" contains high frequency components that can be removed by an appropriate FIR filter.  At it's most basic a *boxcar* filter implements a simple rolling-mean, and is an FIR filter with all coefficients equal to 1, the level of smoothing determined by the length of the filter. A more sophisticated approach and greater control is afforded by using the coefficients, however it is rather complex maths to determine the coefficients - there are filter design tools that will do this - Matlab is often used.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a generic cubic spline fitting function that can be applied to any dimensional euclidean and quaternion data, which might fit (no pun intended) your purpose. I don't know how well the fitting compares to other algorithms though since only the input data keys are considered as potential spline key placement, but you can have a look at it here: http://sourceforge.net/p/spinxengine/code/HEAD/tree/sxp_src/core/math/parametric.inl (fit_spline function).

For creating cyclic motion you should be able to replicate the keys before and after the fitted data sequence and modify the function so that it forces creation of a key at end of the cycle. This is relatively simple function so it shouldn't be a big effort to modify it like that. You need to also setup a spline fitting constraint to define in what kind of conditions new splines are created (e.g. what's distance tolerance from fitted data to input data, etc.)

Cheers, Jarkko

Comment: This looks useful. I considered spines as a possibility, wasn't sure about implementation and such. Is there documentation for this beside the comments?